# Connection refused when trying to login with Intellij IDEA Upsource plugin

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, upsource

I'm trying to login to an Intellij Upsource server using the Upsource Integration plugin.

After configuring the Upsource URL an clicking on "Test connection" the browser is opened and I'm prompted to login to the Upsource server. This fails with a "Connection refused" error in my browser.

I can see in the Intellij log file that there is a connection attempt to my computer on the port 3100:

```
2018-06-01 07:59:00,706 [  82261]  DEBUG - idea.authorization.AuthManager - Authorization URL: http://x.x.x.x:8888/hub/api/rest/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=upsource-idea-plugin&scope=8a2cb56b-2c52-4533-ab55-f3d9c6a1be03&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3100&request_credentials=required&access_type=offline
```

They MacOS firewall is enabled, but shows no blocked attempts. IntelliJ is configured to allow incoming connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the MacOS network proxy settings (since the computer was configured to use a proxy for HTTP & HTTPS) - after adding `localhost` to the list of Hosts & Domains that should be bypassed, the authentication works.